# Sublime text - snippet with capitalization of param first letter

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext-snippet

I want to make snippet for Sublime Text 2 or 3 which will produce the following code:

```
initial - somename
with upper case - Somename
```

and `somename` is text which will be always different.

My draft for this:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
initial - ${2:somename}
with upper case - ${2:somename}
]]></content>
</snippet>
```

But how can I uppercase only first letter in parameter?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Final variant:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
initial - ${1:somename}
with upper case - ${1/(.+)/\u$1/g}
]]></content>
</snippet>
```

Comment: Works great for me. I also found these resources helpful. Thought I'd post them here in case anyone else finds them useful: [Sublime Text Unofficial Documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) / [Boost Syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html)

Comment: For me, using Sublime 3, it only works if you catch one character at a time with: `${1/(.)/\u$1/g}`

Comment: @LucasSiqueira, this will not work as it capitalizes all letters